# Get every column in database that contains only Null records

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I am responsible for a poorly designed legacy application that has 700+ MSSQL tables and plenty of columns that are completely unused. I would like to run a script to return the column and table name of every column that has only null records. Does anyone have any suggestions on I could accomplish this?

[image: Results from select * from sys.schemas]

Comment: **Dynamic SQL** or procedural code (in an application as opposed to T-SQL) as you'll essentially need to query every table. It's not a super easy task, nor will it likely be quick to run either. You'll likely want to use the system **DMVs** like `sys.tables` and `sys.columns` to help you get a list of your Tables and their nullable columns.

Comment: Once you get the list of `NULL` columns be careful with what you're gonna do with them. Unfortunately the poorly designed legacy app might reference those columns (to insert `NULL` values) so just removing them can cause you problems.

Answer (score 2):

As per my comment, the actual querying of the tables to check which nullable columns are completely `NULL` is the more difficult part to this problem.

To get you started you can use **Dynamic SQL** and the system **DMVs** to build the queries you'll need like this:

```
-- Temp table to store the results for later
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS #Results
CREATE TABLE #Results (TableName VARCHAR(1000), ColumnName VARCHAR(1000), RowsCount INT, NonNullCount INT)

-- Dynamic SQL variable to execute after we build it out recursively
DECLARE @DynamicSQL NVARCHAR(MAX) = ''

-- Uses the sys DMVs to recursively build which columns and tables to query
SELECT @DynamicSQL = @DynamicSQL + 
'
     INSERT INTO #Results
     SELECT ' + S.[name] + '.' + T.[name] + ' AS TableName, ' + C.[name] + ' AS ColumnName, COUNT(*) AS RowsCount, COUNT([' + C.[name] + ']) AS NonNullCount 
     FROM [' + S.[name] + '].[' + T.[name] + '];
'
FROM sys.Tables AS T
INNER JOIN sys.Schemas AS S
     ON T.[schema_id] = S.[schema_id]
INNER JOIN sys.Columns AS C
     ON OBJECT_ID(S.[name] + '.' + T.[name]) = C.[object_id]
WHERE C.is_nullable = 1;

-- PRINT @DynamicSQL -- Used for debugging
-- Executes the above dynamic SQL
EXEC sp_ExecuteSQL @DynamicSQL; 

-- Get the final results of which columns only contain NULLs
SELECT TableName, ColumnName
FROM #Results
WHERE RowsCount > 0 -- If the RowsCount is 0 then the table is empty so can't determine if the column only contains NULLs when there's no rows to begin with (but you can remove this predicate if you want to include empty tables too)
     AND NonNullCount = 0 -- If the non null count is 0 then the column only contains NULLs
ORDER BY TableName, ColumnName
```

The above *theoretically* should answer the question. I had to type it on my phone and from memory, so if there's any minor syntactical errors, let me know and I can easily fix. You can also switch the comments around on the line that prints the dynamic SQL with the one that executes it, to help debug any syntactical issues with the dynamic SQL.

Comment: you typed this on your phone?  my hat is off to you, sir.  I do suggest that instead of counting the non-null rows that a simple exist would be more efficient and fit requirements without the need to do a full table scan x column count for 700+ tables... although if mostly empty probably a wash.

Comment: @JonathanFite Yea haha, most times I only have my phone at hand, and will write all my answers while the website is in mobile mode / without the desktop version of the website's editor. Yea there's definitely a lot of performance improvements I'm sure can be made; I just decided to type what first came to mind lol. For example, it *may* be more performant to `UNION ALL` the individual queries of the dynamic SQL as opposed to doing 700+ `INSERT INTO`s but would need to be tested. I've found too many `UNION ALL` operators can even cause the SQL optimizer to falter.

Comment: @JonathanFite Also we share the same first name, so my hat is off to you as well, cheers. 

Comment: To improve performance, check for existance rather than counting rows, i.e. IF EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM mytable WHERE mycolumn IS NOT NULL)
 SELECT 'mytable.mycolumn'

Comment: This was very helpful but the INNER JOIN on sys.Columns does not retrieve all of my tables. We have some tables using the dbo schema and the script above will get those but we also have alot of old tables using a 'informix' schema. Is there a way I can include those as well?

Comment: @shaunteezie I'd need a little more information / context because the above query does get all tables for all schemas. Perhaps some of the tables you were missing don't have any nullable columns which I'm filtering out with this predicate `WHERE C.is_nullable = 1`? If not, and a valid case is missing, a screenshot of the output of my main query on the system views might help us debug. (Also a screenshot of just `SELECT * FROM sys.schemas` would be helpful too). Note the query I provided in my answer only works in the database it's executed under. If you have multiple databases you need to...

Comment: ...check, then you'll need to either run this under the context of each one manually, or do additional scripting to automatically hit each database which can be accomplished with another layer of **Dynamic SQL** or possibly using the system procedure `sp_MSForEachDB`.

Comment: I'm not sure how to format this in a SO comment:
dbo 1 1
guest 2 2
INFORMATION_SCHEMA 3 3
sys 4 4
informix 5 20
redacted_meta 6 20
redacted_sn 7 20
report 8 20
db_owner 16384 20
db_accessadmin 16385 16385
db_securityadmin 16386 16386
db_ddladmin 16387 16387
db_backupoperator 16389 16389
db_datareader 16390 20
db_datawriter 16391 20
db_denydatareader 16392 16392
db_denydatawriter 16393 16393

Comment: @shaunteezie Sorry not sure what you were trying to send in the comment, but anything useful should be added to your post instead. You'll be able to format things that way then too.

Comment: @shaunteezie It looks like `informix` is in your `sys.schemas` system view. If you run `SELECT T.[name] AS TableName FROM sys.Tables AS T
INNER JOIN sys.Schemas AS S
     ON T.[schema_id] = S.[schema_id]
INNER JOIN sys.Columns AS C
     ON OBJECT_ID(T.[name]) = C.[object_id]
WHERE C.is_nullable = 1 AND S.[name] = 'informix';` do you see tables from that schema? If not, if you remove the `C.is_nullable = 1` predicate, do you see them now?

Comment: @J.D. I tried it both ways and nothing is returned with either query.

Comment: @shaunteezie Interesting, and what do you get when you run this query? `SELECT T.[name] AS TableName FROM sys.Tables AS T
INNER JOIN sys.Schemas AS S
     ON T.[schema_id] = S.[schema_id] WHERE S.[name] = 'informix';`

Comment: @J.D.Your query returned all of the tables with the informix schema.

Comment: @shaunteezie Apologies, I finally realized my mistake. I'm so used to not using schemas outside of `dbo` that I didn't realize the `OBJECT_ID()` function defaults to `dbo` schema when you don't provide the schema name as part of the object name you pass in. Anyway, please see my updated answer which fixes your issue and should now include those missing tables from your `informix` schema. Specifically this is the line of code I changed my answer: `ON OBJECT_ID(S.[name] + '.' + T.[name]) = C.[object_id]`. Apologies again for not realizing sooner.